# How to loop through posts out of order?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looping through Wordpress posts, but I need to use the data out of the order it is received. I am querying 4 posts. I need the order they're returned to be: 1, 4, 2, 3, ordered by date. I'll keep the example below as simple as possible:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$cat.'&posts_per_page=4&orderby=date' );

foreach ($posts as $post) {

  echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a><br /><br />'; // The actual content is more complicated- keeping it simple for this example

} // end foreach
```

Now, what do I have to do in order to echo the posts out of order? (1, 4, 2, 3)

Comment: @DaveChen No, not random, but to put them in that specific order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an idea:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$cat.'&posts_per_page=4&orderby=date' );
$ordered_posts = array();

foreach ($posts as $post)
  $ordered_posts[] = '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a><br /><br />';

$order = array(1, 4, 3, 2);
$size  = count($order);

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
    echo $ordered_posts[$order[$i] - 1];
```

You start by storing all the posts in order, and then using an array to map sequence, you can output them in a modified order.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<?php
$posts = array();
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$cat.'&posts_per_page=4&orderby=date' );

$myposts = get_posts( $the_query);
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) 
{
   $posts[] += $post->ID;
}

echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($posts[0]).'" title="'.get_the_title($posts[0]).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title($posts[0]).'</a><br /><br />';

echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($posts[4]).'" title="'.get_the_title($posts[4]).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title($posts[4]).'</a><br /><br />';

echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($posts[1]).'" title="'.get_the_title($posts[1]).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title($posts[1]).'</a><br /><br />';

echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink($posts[2]).'" title="'.get_the_title($posts[2]).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title($posts[2]).'</a><br /><br />';

?>
```

Comment: Looking at Dave's answer, his seems to be better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, which will just sort the `$posts` array based on the order you specify in the `$order` array:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat='.$cat.'&posts_per_page=4&orderby=date' );
$posts = get_posts($the_query);
$order = array(1, 4, 2, 3);

usort($posts, function ($a, $b) use ($posts, $order) {
    $a_key = array_search($a, $posts);
    $b_key = array_search($b, $posts);
    $a_order = array_search($a_key + 1, $order);
    $b_order = array_search($b_key + 1, $order);
    return $a_order - $b_order;
});

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    //do stuff
}
```

If you want to preserve their indexes, use `uasort` instead of `usort`.

Answer (score 0):

For a non programatic way, use [Simple Custom Post Order](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-post-order/). Basically it lets you drag and drop the posts in the WP backend. Very easy, no setup.